# Watir WebDriver select list without standard html

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Just started using Watir-WebDriver, came across website with and facing an problem.

```
1) Goto "https://www.smiles.com.br/home"
2) How to get/set values to drop down selections like selecting number of adults in "Adulto"
```

Selection list initially is hidden but when clicked on the text field it become visible in browser.
But when I tried using to click and check its existence it returning false

```
1) b.text_field(:id => "inputOrigin").click

2) irb(main):049:0> b.a(:id => 'yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1467245841395_1777').exist?
=> false
```

Since its not actually a selection list, how do I set values?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is dynamic so it changes every time. It looks like it might be based on the time, but this should be sufficiently unique:

```
b.link(id: /^yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response But how do i set the value: b.link(id: /^yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_/).set "value" doesnt work

Comment: Since it's a link, use `.click` instead of `.set`.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on `<input id="inputOrigin">`, you need to perform another click to trigger the "dropdown" list.  Otherwise, you'll get a `element not visible` error. You could do something like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto('https://www.smiles.com.br/home')

b.text_field(:id => "inputOrigin").when_present.click
b.div(:id => "dk_container_qtdAdult").when_present.click           #trigger "dropdown" menu

b.div(:class => "adult").link(:text => "02").when_present.click
# b.div(:class => "adult").link(:data_dk_dropdown_value => "02").click      #an alternative
```

Once selected, you can get the option using the `.text` method:

```
puts b.div(:id => "dk_container_qtdAdult").link(:class => "dk_toggle dk_label").text
```

Lastly, you could use regex locators, but you might have more success by trying to identify more discrete (and--ideally--unique) page elements.

Comment: Tried "b.div(:class => "adult").link(:text => "02").click" still gives element not visible.

Comment: You can try chaining `when_present`: `b.div(:class => "adult").link(:text => "02").when_present.click`.   This approach works for me locally.

Comment: @orde - Thanks for all of your assistance answering Watir questions on Stack Overflow. Please contact me through my profile so I can send you a link to be added to the Watir team - http://stackoverflow.com/teams/244/watir